# Tableau Server Api populate csv with multiple value filters

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm trying to use the Tableau Server Client with Python to generate a `csv` file from a particular view which has a filter with multiple options, as shown in the image below.
[image]

Is it possible to specify multiple values in the `CSVRequestOptions` for the same filter?

I've tried to call the `vf` method multiple times with the same filter name (`client`) as the first parameter, but it only returns the data for the latter one.

```
def view_populate_csv(view_item):
    csv_req_option = TSC.CSVRequestOptions()
    csv_req_option.vf("client", "client1")
    csv_req_option.vf("client", "client2")
    csv_req_option.vf("client", "client3")

    server.views.populate_csv(view_item, csv_req_option)
    with open("./view_data.csv", "wb") as f:
        f.write(b"".join(view_item.csv))
```

Also tried to add only the "(All)" option, but it won't return anything
`csv_req_option.vf("client", "(all)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

csv_req_option.vf("client", "client1,client2,client3")